# Arduino IDE Blinking led when using multiple sensors/if else statements

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to get my LED to blink if multiple conditions are met.
The following code works fine without the teller1 part inside the if else statement, but when i add the elapsedmillis counter to the if else statement the led doesn't blink, even when all of the conditions are met.

Any help?

Here's my code:

```
#define trigPin D7
#define echoPin D8
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
elapsedMillis teller1;
elapsedMillis teller2;

const int RED = D5; //het ‘rode’ pootje zit in D5
const int GREEN = D4; //etc. 
const int BLUE = D3;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
pinMode(D6, OUTPUT);
pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);
pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  if (teller1 > 500) {

  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);

  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;

    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");

  if ((sensorValue > 20) && (distance > 20) && (teller1 < 250)) {

  analogWrite(RED, 255);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0); 
  } else if ((sensorValue > 20) && (distance > 20) && (teller1 > 250)) {
  analogWrite(RED, 0);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0); 
  }

  else if (sensorValue <20) {
  analogWrite(RED, 0);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
  }


  teller1 = 0;
  } 

  delay(50);

}
```

EDIT: I think i've fixed it, but i'm not sure this would be considered well written or the proper way of doing this:

```
#define trigPin D7          //trigger pin voor de echo sensor definieren op D7
#define echoPin D8          //echo pin voor de echo sensor definieren op D8
#include <elapsedMillis.h>  //elapsedMillis library aanroepen
elapsedMillis teller1;      //teller1 aanmaken
elapsedMillis teller2;      //teller 2 aanmaken

const int RED = D5; //het ‘rode’ pootje zit in D5
const int GREEN = D4; //etc. 
const int BLUE = D3;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);   //confirugeer D7 als output
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);    //confirugeer D8 als input
pinMode(D6, OUTPUT);        //confirugeer D6 als output
pinMode(RED, OUTPUT);       //confirugeer D5 als output
pinMode(GREEN, OUTPUT);     //confirugeer D4 als output
pinMode(BLUE, OUTPUT);      //confirugeer D3 als output

}

void loop() {

  if (teller1 > 500) {      //als de timer boven 500ms komt

  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0); //sla de sensorwaarde op
  Serial.println(sensorValue);      //druk de sensorwaarde af in de serial monitor

  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2) / 29.1;   //formule om afstand te berekenen

    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println(" cm");

  if ((sensorValue > 20) && (distance < 20) && (teller1 < 750)) {

  analogWrite(RED, 255);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0); 
  digitalWrite(D6, HIGH);
  } 

  else if (sensorValue <20) {
  analogWrite(RED, 0);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0);
  }


  teller1 = 0;
  } else if (teller1 < 250) {
   analogWrite(RED, 0);
  analogWrite(GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(BLUE, 0); 
  digitalWrite(D6, LOW);
  }

  delay(50);
  Serial.print("teller");
Serial.println(teller1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `void loop()` starts with `if (teller1 > 500) {`.
Then, when checking the sensor values it says

```
if ((sensorValue > 20) && (distance > 20) && (teller1 < 250)) {
  analogWrite(RED, 255);
```

teller1 can't be >500 and <250 at the same time.

Edit after comment:

```
void loop(){
    if (teller1 > 500) {
    //read sensor values
    teller1 = 0;
    }

    if (sensorValue > 20 && distance > 20) {
    //power led
    teller2 = 0;
    }
    if (sensorValue <20 || teller2 > 250){
    //unpower led
    }
}
```

Comment: That'd work if it wasnt for the fact that it resets teller1 to 0 after 500ms :/ Plugging in the code made it go dark for the first .5 seconds, then stay on for the rest of the time. I think it'd be way easier if i have the if else statements outside of the first if loop within teller 1, but then i run into the problem that my variables like distance arent globally defined, and i don't know how to do so. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Anyway, i think i've fixed it, although i'm not sure if it's a really messy hack-ish way

Comment: I wasn't understanding all the time checking. Is the purpose 1 - to check the sensor every 0.5s  2 - if minimal distance, then light led for 0.25s ? Anyways, there is no need to do the reading of the sensor and the lighting of the led in the same timeloop. I've added some pseudocode that shows a slightly different approach to the issue, that will make timing a little easier I think.